# http.ListenAndServeTLS with multiple certificates

Tags: ssl, go, https

How do I ListenAndServeTLS with multiple domains? I see the function accepts a cert and key file, but I believe the key file may only contain a single private key. I have a few private keys, for different certificate chains.

Comment: you probably should be interested in the https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert that will issue LetsEncrypt certs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`http.ListenAndServeTLS` is meant to be present a bare minimal configuration. If you want to add other options, you can create an `http.Server` with a custom `tls.Config`. You can then either manually map names in `tls.Config.NameToCertificate`, or call `BuildNameToCertificate()` to build the map programatically.

You can still use `Server.ListenAndServeTLS` however, since it will load the certs in the config as well a cert passed in via the methods args.

```
cfg := &tls.Config{}

cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("cert_one.pem", "key_one.pem")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

cfg.Certificates = append(cfg.Certificates, cert)
// keep adding remaining certs to cfg.Certificates

cfg.BuildNameToCertificate()

server := http.Server{
    Addr:      "127.0.0.1:443",
    Handler:   myHandler,
    TLSConfig: cfg,
}

server.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm no Go user myself but if you want to use multiple certificates on the same TLS listener you must have some way to decide which certificate should be used once a client connects because only a single certificate + chain can be sent inside the TLS handshake.

The main use case for this is [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). With SNI you have multiple certificates and you want to select the appropriate one based on the name the client asked for within the TLS handshake.

Searching for [go sni server](https://www.google.com/search?q=go+sni+server) results in [this post from 2013](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/rUm2iYTdrU4). This post shows that using multiple certificates with ListenAndServeTLS is not possible (or was in 2013) but it also shows how to achieve the necessary functionality.