# How can I add new certificates without restart application?

Tags: ssl, go

I want to use http.ListenAndServeTLS with multiple certificates and add new certificates without restart application.

I found an example of using multiple certificates, but I can not add new certificates after startup.([http.ListenAndServeTLS with multiple certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175300/http-listenandservetls-with-multiple-certificates))

I have also found an example of updating a certificate, and only one can be used and updated. But i can not add more.([Is there a way to update the TLS certificates in a net/http server without any downtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473201/is-there-a-way-to-update-the-tls-certificates-in-a-net-http-server-without-any-d))

Comment: What do you mean that "only one can be used and updated."? The `GetCertificate` function is meant to load any key you want dynamically.

Comment: How can I load multiple certificates by using GetCertificate?

Comment: The second link would definitely do it. You just need to write the logic to select the correct certificate to be returned from `GetCertificateFunc`.

Comment: You are right, thank you.